# Support of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a measurable function bounded by $M$ and supported on a set $E$. There is a sequence of simple functions $\{\varphi_n\}$ such that $|\varphi_k(x)|\leq|\varphi_{k+1}(x)|$ for all $k$ and $x$ and $\varphi_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ for all $x$.

In the text I am reading, the authors claim that each $\varphi_n$ in the sequence is also supported by $E$. But why is this true? Can't one of the $\varphi_n$ vanish at a given $x$, yet $f$ not vanish there as the sequence is increasing?

Comment: Well this is not mandatory indeed but you can always build that function sequence such that all of them are supported by $E$.

Comment: The theorem doesn't state you can't do it without that condition, only that you can with that condition. Presumably, that condition is useful in some cases.

Comment: I imagine they meant that the support of the simple functions is contained in $E$?

Comment: "Can't one of the $\varphi_n$ vanish at a given $x$, yet $f$ not vanish there as the sequence is increasing?" Yes. However, the authors claim that if $f$ vanishes at $x$, all $\varphi_n$ vanish there as well.

Comment: Why can we always construct a sequence $\varphi_n$ as such?

Comment: what does "for all $x$ mean"? For all $x\in E?$